# Include a text file *as is* in (Python) Sphinx Docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx

(using Python-Sphinx Documentation tool)

I have a `.txt` log file I'd like to build into `_build/html` *unaltered*.  What do I need to alter in `conf.py`, `index.rst`, etc.

Here is the layout:

```
src/
    index.rst
    some_doc.rst
    somefile.txt
```

How do I get `somefile.txt` into the html build?  I tried adding a line like this
to `index.rst`:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   some_doc
   "somefile.txt"
```

hoping it would work by magic, but no magic here!

Assuming this is even possible, what would I put in `some_doc.rst` to refer/link 
to that file?

**Note**  Yes, I'm aware I could put it in **/static** and just be done with it, 
but that seems like a total hack, and ugly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct answer is the [`:download:` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-download).

Cf:  [Georg's answer on the Sphinx Mailing List](http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/2d9cdbf30940a12b/103091de78357514?lnk=gst&q=include#103091de78357514)

Comment: How is adding a download link the answer to "how to build in a file unaltered?"

Comment: The mailing list link in the answer is dead. Is this the message that you refer to? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sphinx-users/LZzb8wlAoSs/FHU1eN6RMBAJ

Answer (score 31):

I think you can include an external document fragment, as described here:

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment

From that text, something like this should do it:

```
.. include:: inclusion.txt
   :literal:
```

Comment: not quite what I want, but I'm looking over :raw: and other roles.  I'm not trying to include a "fragment", but bring over a while file *as is*, so I can link to it, a la ->  if you look at the `log <mylog.txt>`_ ....

Comment: this does answer the question's title, which hints at a different question altogether ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following in sphinx

```
.. literalinclude:: file.txt
   :text:
```

It will show the content of the file, as if it were in a code block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).