# In Python sphinx, how to link to a file in _static directory

Tags: python-sphinx

I have some code and data samples I copy to `_static` directory and I would like to link to those files in documentation, something like:

```
.. _pca-run.py: _static/example.data
```

But the problem is that sphinx does not create a proper relative link to this file, but just copies the values as it is. So for nested files where `_static` is not in the same directory links do not work.

Comment: Seems there is a ``:download:`` role: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921724/include-a-text-file-as-is-in-python-sphinx-docs

Answer (score 20):

What you want is the `:download:` text role. (as Mitar mentioned in his comment).

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-download

Using this will tell Sphinx to copy the given file to a "_downloads" directory and create a hyperlink to it.  This was originally intended to be used for downloadable files, like perhaps PDFs (in html output) or tarballs, or whatever.  It works just fine for any other non-ReST file though.

If you really wanted, you could write an extension to do this, but I've never seen a need to, since `:download:` does exactly what I want.

Comment: But ``:download:`` is very verbose. If you want to use it multiple times, it gets tiresome.

Comment: Are you aware of any role that works like `:download:` but accepts wildcards (or `glob` patterns)?

Comment: @Unode: I'm not sure I understand why you would want to do that, but you'd probably have to create your own extension.  It's not that hard though.  See [sphinx-contrib](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/) for a bunch of examples.

Comment: @KevinHorn I want to automatically have a list of download links to all files that are in a certain folder and match a certain pattern, say: `*.doc`

Comment: @Unode: I think you'd need to write your own extension for that.

Answer (score 10):

Just find the right answer to this for **images**: preprend the path of the target file with `/`. For images referenced from an `automodule`

```
.. image:: some_file.png
```

will refer to the file `some_file.png` relative to the python file currently being processed, while

```
.. image:: /some_file.png
```

will refer to the file `some_file.png` relative to the location of the `conf.py`. This way, there is no need to pollute the source hierarchy with images.

Comment: If you separate `source` and `build` directories, you need to do the same. It means Sphinx does not look for the relative location of `conf.py`, but `html_static_path` variable inside `conf.py`.