# How to do a link to a file in rst with sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing a documentation and I would like to include links to pdf files or zip archives. How can I achieve that using rst language and sphinx ?

If I do that

```
here is a pdf file : `pdf <doc/mypdf.pdf>`_
```

It does not work because, during the compilation sphinx do not copy the contains of the doc directory (I use the makefile generated by sphinx-quickstart).

On the contrary, using the `image` directive :

```
.. image:: img/plop.png
```

sphinx does copy the plop.png image in build directory. How can I obtain the same behavior for pdf or zip archive ?

Comment: try the `:download:` role -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921724/include-a-text-file-as-is-in-python-sphinx-docs/

Answer (score 80):

A solution is to use the `:download:` “role” (detailed in the [sphinx documentation on roles](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#referencing-downloadable-files)).

Here is a short example assuming you have a file `mypdf.pdf` in a directory `doc`. The directory `doc` and your rst file must be in the same directory:

```
here is a pdf file :download:`pdf <doc/mypdf.pdf>`
```

Note that you mustn't put a blank space between `:download:` and the path to the file.

Comment: Alternatively, you can put your file in the `_static` folder (or whatever you configured that to be), and reference it directly from there.

Comment: Link is outdated unfortunately. I did not find the updated version.

Comment: @Mayou36: link to the :download: role documention is now fixed.

Comment: Just a small note for these trying to use `:download:` with no success. Files you want to be accessible by `:download:\`name <_static/file.pdf>\`` need to be present in `docs/source/_static/` when you are building HTML. You can not just put them to `docs/build/html/_static/` afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

The `image` directive only works for HTML with PDF files.

```
.. image:: doc/mypdf.pdf
```

DO NOT use it, because it is misleading. Thanks to comment of G. Milde.

Comment: This will only show a link to the PDF-file, not display the file itself (which is something I am struggling with at the moment).

Comment: @1313e OP asked for a link. Have a try with `.. figure:: doc/mypdf.pdf` to show the PDF.

Comment: It works for HTML, as the PDF image format is not supported by most HTML browsers. Abusing the "image" directive for download links is missleading and error prone, though. Exporting to LaTeX would include the PDF as image.