# How to do a link to a file in rst with sphinx and get pdf output?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, pdflatex

In rst and sphinx, I want to link to an external pdf file **after I have created pdf output**. I understand that I have to use the `:download:` directive, e.g.

```
here is a pdf file :download:`pdf <doc/mypdf.pdf>`
```

While this **works fine generating html output**, it does not work for pdfs generated from sphinx (using `make pdf` or `make latexpdf`). 'Does not work' means that while the links are shown, the document does not open if I click on the link. It only opens for html links in the document.

I am aware of the question and answer:
[How to do a link to a file in rst with sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345922/how-to-do-a-link-to-a-file-in-rst-with-sphinx)  ,

but this does not help me, since this only covers html output.

While I am not sure about rst2pdf, at least Latex should contain directives which allow to include links to pdfs which can be clicked on, e.g. hyperref as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files/41605#41605

Any ideas? Is this possible at all?

**EDIT:**
With `make latexpdf, links to pdfs such as

```
:download:`PDF-document <filename.pdf>`
```

get translated into latex as

```
\sphinxcode{PDF-document}
```

`\sphinxcode` seems to refer to some kind of latex macro, but even with the newest version of Tex live installed, this macro does not get resolved in a way that links would be clickable. Furthermore, the link itself (`PDF-document`) is already lost in the latex document.

**EDIT 2:**

A file sphinx.sty gets created by `make pdflatex` which defines the commands `\sphinxincludegraphics` (for including images, where the links work) and `\sphinxcode` (for including pdfs,where the link does not work). I am adding a latex tag to this post, maybe someone there can help to understand the problem.